Was suffix -alis derived from alis or alius? Or are they unrelated?
Oxford Latin Dictionary says:

alis see alius.
-alis, -ale  adjl.  suff.  Collat.  w.  -aris,  which  is used when the base contains an l  (but cf.  cleacalis, limitalis);  formed  from
nouns  (exitialis,  officialis, regalis).

Was suffix -alis derived from alis or alius? Or are they unrelated?

Is there any reason to think they'd be connected?

As far as I know, they're unrelated.
De Vaan derives alius from PIE *h₂el- "other" (compare Greek allos, Latin alter), which makes perfect sense. He doesn't list -ālis since it's not a lexeme in its own right, but it's hard to see how "pertaining to" could come from "other"; looking online, some sites suggest a link to the second half of ind-olēs ("innate"), in which case it would would come from an unrelated *h₂el- "nourish", as in alō.

Wiktionary offers:

From Proto-Indo-European *-li-, which later dissimilated into an early version of -āris (e.g., mīlitāris). Perhaps connected to *h₂el- (“to grow”) (cf. the sense of indolēs, from this root).

So, apparently there's no connection with alis/alius ("other").
